# SQLiteDatabase query method

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am using the query method of SQLiteDatabase. How do I do a query that gives me items by a particular STRING?

this query :

```
    public ArrayList<RecipeInfo> getTypeRecipe() {
    ArrayList<RecipeInfo> recipeInfo = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_RECIPES_NAME, TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS,
                 RECIPE_COLUMN_TITLE+" =lunch", null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            RecipeInfo ri=cursorToRecipes(cursor);
            recipeInfo.add(ri);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    catch (Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return recipeInfo;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what `TABLE_RECIPES_NAME`, `TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS` and `RECIPE_COLUMN_TITLE` are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the record corresponding to a particular String as its title, (say,  title="lunch"), you do the query as follows:

```
cursor=db.query(TABLE_RECIPES_NAME, TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS,
                 "title=?", new String[]{"lunch"}, null, null, null);
```

OR

```
cursor=db.query(TABLE_RECIPES_NAME, TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS,
                     RECIPE_COLUMN_TITLE+"=?", new String[]{"lunch"}, null, null, null);
```

This will query the table TABLE_RECIPES_NAME and return all columns specified by  TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS , corresponding to the record where "title" is "lunch".

Answer (score 0):

```
//database info
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cookpadDB";

//recipe table
private static final String TABLE_RECIPES_NAME ="recipes";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_ID ="id";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_TITLE ="title";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION ="description";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_FOOD_IMAGE = "food_image";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_TYPE="type";
private static final String RECIPE_COLUMN_LIKE="like";
private static final String[] TABLE_RECIPE_COLUMNS = {RECIPE_COLUMN_ID, RECIPE_COLUMN_TITLE,
        RECIPE_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, RECIPE_COLUMN_FOOD_IMAGE,RECIPE_COLUMN_TYPE,RECIPE_COLUMN_LIKE};
```